# PhpStorm: Automatically deploy .css file after file watcher transpiled .scss file

Tags: deployment, sass, phpstorm, file-watcher, transpiler

I am deploying my project automatically to a remote server. All files that are changed are automatically uploaded to the server, so this is OK.
I have a file watcher (Compass SCSS) to transpile my .scss into .css. When the .sccs file is changed it is uploaded to the remote server, but the transpiled .css file is not.

In the deployment options the "Upload external changes" checkbox is checked (see screenshot).
In the file watcher settings the "Output paths to refresh" is set to the folder where the transpiled .css file is located.

However, the .css file is not automatically uploaded when it is changed.
When I set the focus onto a window outside of PhpStorm and then back onto the PhpStorm IDE the .css file is uploaded, but I want to avoid changing windows to get it uploaded.

Is there something I am missing?

[image: Deployment options screenshot]

Comment: What is your IDE version? What's your setup (source and final files)? Accordingly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16410 it should be working.

Comment: This guy seem to have it working: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37189198/783119

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback!

It is solved now, I was using absolute paths in the file watcher settings instead of the macro placeholders (like $ProjectFileDir$).
For some reason PhpStorm is not detecting changes when absolute paths are used.

// B