# PhpStorm Sync Less and CSS File

Tags: css, synchronization, less, phpstorm

I have a folder structure like in the following picture. The less node.js I would compile with. I am calling the compiled CSS file in the meta-tag section.

[image]

When a change is made in the less file, the CSS file is automatically loaded on to the server I want to be.

Summary : If style.less changes in style.css to upload to the server.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Tools->Deployment->Options ->  Upload external changes chose.

[image]